# Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put my result of variables in an object that eventually outputs in a csv file like this

```
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Merk" -Value $Desktop.CsManufacturer
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Model" -Value $Desktop.CsModel
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "S/n" -Value $Desktop.BiosSeralNumber

$output | Export-Csv -Path $GL\info.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
```

(this is only part of the entire code)

My goal is to have a file that i can run on a PC at first from a USB stick and later from a AD startup script that extracts data from the Desktop, Monitor, OS,... and put it in a CSV file but i'm always getting the error "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid." which means there is something wrong with the value of name in the code above i suppose? I'm still a rookie in this stuff so i'm just trying everything out.

Alternatively If anyone sees me struggle and has a better idea on how to output my variables in a CSV file please tell me.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't explain your symptom. Please try to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using "Add-Member" to create a custom PSObject, try this:

```
$OutPutArray = @()
foreach ($computer in $complist) {
    $output = [Ordered]@{
        "Make" = $computer.CsManufacturer
        "Model" = $computer.CsModel
        "S/n" = $computer.BiosSerialNumber
    }
    $OutPutArray += New-Object PSOBject -Property $output
}
$OutPutArray | Export-csv <path to file> -NoTypeInformation
```

**EDIT** suggested alternative with a [PSCustomObject] and directly assigned output of the foreach.

```
$OutPutArray = foreach ($computer in $complist) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Make"  = $computer.CsManufacturer
        "Model" = $computer.CsModel
        "S/n"   = $computer.BiosSerialNumber
    }
}
$OutPutArray | Export-csv <path to file> -NoTypeInformation
```

The resulting object is the same, but a tad more efficient.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a list of computers you are running this on.

Comment: I don't have a list yet, i'm making this script to start making a list of all the computers here.

Comment: Is it possible to get the response in the csv file without the " ? just to import on the commas

Comment: Why not assign the whole foreach directly to `$OutPutArray`, the intermediate `$output` isn't necessary then. `[ordered]` => `[PSCustomObject]`

Comment: @LotPings So I tried doing something like that and the `$OutPutArray` turns out to be an `OrderedDictionary` object as opposed to the `PSCustomObject` that you might be expecting. I've not yet begun to work with those, but if you simply try to `$OutPutArray | Export-Csv`, then you don't get what you think you get.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Yes, that works with what I'm doing elsewhere. Much thanks. Is there a proper SO etiquette on how to handle this edit?